# Share logins between 2 databases or?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a personal website using a MySQL database (with justhost.com). The registration is very simple and only requres a username, pw, and email. I want to add an Oekaki to my site, but the Oekaki install instructions say it *should* have its own database. If I input the database I am currently using, will that screw it up, or will it create a new table within that database so when a member logs in, they have access to the Wiki and Oekaki under the same username and pw?

Please note I am a database newbie. I am using TikiWiki 6.2 currently and at its initial install of TikiWiki 5 created its own database. If the above won't work in any way, after I create a new database for the Oekaki, what would I have to do so it uses the current registration information from my TikiWiki database without me having to manually enter in every single user one by one for the Oekaki side of the site?

Any information is helpful, even if it just helps me learn a little bit more about databases. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any of these software you mentioned. But i can say in general if a software itsself recommends to use one single database for it you should do it.

I had a similar problem with my wordpress blogs database and another organisational software i installed. The next day all my blogs content was gone forever.

It could be, that for example the software just throws all existing tables away.

So my answer (or better advice) is. Be careful and if you can avoid it, don't throw together two applications in one database.

For the user-table thing you could probably just change one of the systems to use only the user-table of the other system. So nothing will be screwed up. Or if you have the opportunity make a third "General" Database where you just put your users data and use it in both systems.

Comment: Is there a way to link the blank fields of the new database to the existing one?

Comment: What do you mean by "link them"

Comment: To redirect the table to use the information in some fields of another table. When I install the Oekaki, it will create it's own empty database if I don't specify one to use. Is it possible to point the username and pw fields to the current database so they use the same login information?

Comment: I'm not a database expert but i don't think this is possible. You habe to somehow get both softwares sharing one table i think.